# no background when ListView doesn't fill screen on different phone

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I have an app that I am putting together and I have a background on it. There is a header on top and a ListView in the middle. When I have a list in the middle that isn't at least as big as the screen it just shows gray not the background of the parent layout. The weird thing is that this doesn't happen on my older phone, the background fills the whole screen even if the list doesn't. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the xml for HomeActivity, more information in HomeActivity.java -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/common_aboutLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <!-- This is the header on the top of the home screen -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/dynamicBanner"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/header" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <!-- This is the temp pop-up on start -->
        <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"
            android:id="@+id/titleText" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the layout of the list of ringtones. -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/homeListView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
            admob:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
            admob:keywords="Android application"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            admob:backgroundColor="#666666" 
            admob:refreshInterval="30"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The TextView is just a temp thing when the window first opens.

Just looking for some help, Thanks.

Comment: I found out that this has to do with the motorola stupid overScrollFooter (puke on that). I was reading that changing the height to wrap_content would work but it doesn't for me. When I try to do the overScrollFooter="@null" thing like they say in the motorola blog it gives me error about not being able to find the resource. This is stupid, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put All views in RelativeLayout.then put this admob layout and add a tag to plcae this to   bottom of layout

```
like
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    





<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
        admob:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        admob:keywords="Android application"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        admob:backgroundColor="#666666" 
        admob:refreshInterval="30"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>


 and then Header part inside the relative layout
```

android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

and the put the ListView and

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/adLayout"
 android:layout_below=HEADERVIEW
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, I got it working. I did a few things differently, most likely because I had added somethings since I put this code up, but putting those things inside a relative and the other stuff outside worked great, thanks again.